# Rename file shows permission error or not

Tags: windows-7, permissions, rename

A strange issue with renaming files on a Windows Server shared folder using a Windows 7 client system.

If I rename a file from `file101.txt` to `File101.txt` (capital first letter), Windows generates an error that I don't have permission to rename the file. But if I rename the same file from `file101.txt` to `File-101.txt` (capital + dash) there is no error and the file is renamed.

What causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Windows file names are not case sensitive, and thus you are trying to rename a file using the same name. Since capitals are in fact different to lowercase letters, the GUI you are using to do this is seeing them as different (I just tries this on a Windows 10 client using explorer and got exactly the same results).

The GUI sees what it thinks is a valid change and calls the Windows Kernel (the OS itself) which gets an error somewhere during the process and tells the GUI - 'no you can't do that'. This translates into not having permissions.

And thinking about it, it's true: you don't have permission to do that, and in fact no-one does.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the idea. One thing I noticed a few minutes ago is that I can capitalize files in a different shared folder. So it appears that some folders won't allow such minor changes to filenames, while others do.